# Dynamic HTML5 video playlist that has no pause between videos?

Tags: javascript, html, video, playlist, http-live-streaming

**Background:**
The videos in my play list are all 1/2 second to 4 seconds long.
The playlist is randomly generated on page load.

**Strategies**

*HLS Streaming* - I've implemented this strategy (m3u8 playlists) and it works, but there were several issues with it.

*Preloading all the vidoes* - I am lacking experience and in-depth knowledge of HTML5 video. I have implemented a demo that preloads all the videos in separate `<video>` tags and then switches them in and out as needed. This works in Chrome, has frequent pauses in Safari, and violently crashes OSX in Firefox.

Is there a better way to do this?
Maybe a better strategy to preloading the videos?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I had a similar issue with audio tones that I needed to play back to back.  What I did is load the audio files via XHR into array buffers and played them from the array buffers.  Maybe you can do something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've never heard of XHR before.
[This](https://simpl.info/video/offline/) seems very promising. I'll try it out and post back. Thanks

Comment: xhr is just an Ajax request.  just do responseType as an array buffer.  Let me know if you need help writing some pseudo code

Comment: I've got an initial version working!
There's a very brief white flash when changing videos, so my next test is to implement two video tags and switch them in and out. I think this will fix the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That is awesome... Post a link

Comment: Have you got something new ? Could you provide a demo ?